# is it possible to install ROS indigo along with kinetic

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I already installed ROS kinetic, however, I couldn't find installation for turtlebot on kinetic, only indigo is supported. Can I find a supported installation for kinetic?
Also, can I install indigo along with kinetic without collision?

Edit: I was able to install gazebo simulator for turtlebot after long hours, however, every time I try to launch turtlebot_world.launch I get error message as shown in the attached screenshot.[image: image description]
Thank you[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245288/is-it-possible-to-install-ros-indigo-along-with-kinetic/) by [Mina](https://answers.ros.org/users/28187/mina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-10-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-10-09**:
@Mina Please ask a new question about the simulator, it's a new topic. http://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [Mina](https://answers.ros.org/users/28187/mina/) on 2016-10-10**:
That's alright
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo is not supported on 16.04 Xenial.

Please see the supported platforms in [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)

Indigo can be installed from source side by side with Kinetic on Xennial if you're willing to do a little debugging. Most dependencies have not changed miuch so it generally will work.

Most TurtleBot packages are released and available on Kinetic: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=turtlebot

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mina](https://answers.ros.org/users/28187/mina/) on 2016-10-09**:
many of them written (branch:indigo) next to the source, should they work with kinetic?
Also, I don't know how to install these packages after cloning them from github, can you help with that please?
Thanks

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-10-09**:
Directions for installing from source are here: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

You should also read up on the ROS tutorials related to maintaining workspaces: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials